# I'm using a Font Awesome icon in a Twitter Bootstrap Media Object, but it gets cut off

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to use a Font Awesome icon (with `text-size: 180px;` applied) in a Twitter Bootstrap [Media Object](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#media). Specifically, I'm trying to replace the image in the Media Object with the Font Awesome icon.

However, when I open the page, the icon is shifted up and cut off at the top of the Media Object.

I've tried searching for `[font-awesome] [twitter-bootstrap] cut off` on Stack Overflow, which returned 2 results, neither of them helpful. I've also tried setting a negative margin for both the `<i>` tag itself and the parent `<div>`, both with no luck.

Also, I tried to make a JSFiddle, but couldn't make it work, so my site is online at http://strugee.github.com/textingwhiledriving/spreadtheword.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `line-height: 20px;` style associated with `<body>` (inherited from bootstrap.min.css)

if you change your `.socialicon` to

```
.socialicon {
  font-size: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  line-height: 180px; /* or whatever height you desire */
}
```

the icons are not clipped